# Efficient method to move data from Oracle (SQL Developer) to MS SQL Server

Tags: sqlite, ssms, plsqldeveloper, sql-server-2014-express

Daily, I query a few tables in SQL Developer, filtering to prior day activity, adding column to date stamp the data, then export to xlsx. Then I manually import each file to a MS SQL Server via SQL Server Import and Export Wizard. Takes many clicks, much waiting...

I'm essentially creating an archive in SQL Server, the application I'm querying overwrites data daily. I'm not a DBA of either database, I use the archived data to do validations and research.

It's tough to get my org to provide additional software, I've been trying to make this work via SQL Developer, SSMS Express ed, and other standard tools.

I'm looking to make this reasonably automated, either via scripts, scheduled tasks, etc. Appreciate suggestions that would work on my current situation, but if that isn't reasonable, and there's a very reasonable alternative, I can go back to the org to request software/access/assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SSIS to import the data directly from Oracle to SQL Server, unless you need the .xlsx files for another purpose.  You can also export from Oracle to these, then load to SQL Server from these files if you do need the files.  For the date stamp column, a Derived Column can be added within a Data Flow Task using the SSIS `GETDATE()` function for a timestamp in order to achieve the same result.  This function returns a timestamp, and if only the date is necessary the `(DT_DBDATE)` function can cast it to a date data type that's compatible with this data type of SQL Server.  Once you have the SSIS package configured, you can schedule in to run at regular intervals as a SQL Agent job.  I'd also recommend installing the SSIS catalog (SSISDB) and using this the source to run the packages from.  The following links shed more light on these areas.

- [SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/sql-server-integration-services?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Connecting to Oracle from SSIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Data Flow Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/data-flow-task?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Derived Column Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/derived-column-transformation?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Creating SQL Server Agent Jobs for SSIS packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/packages/sql-server-agent-jobs-for-packages?view=sql-server-2017)
- [SSIS Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: SSIS (appears?) to require an Enterprise or Standard edition of SSMS, I only have Express. I'll read up a bit on your links, but I'm not confident this avoids my current limitations.   [Edit) Forgot to thank you for your time - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you may consider (if it is supported in SQL Express) is using the BCP utility, which can be run from command line.

The BCP utility allows you to bulk copy the data from a delimited text file into a SQL Server table.

If you go this approach, things to consider:

- Number of Columns in the source file need to match the number of columns in the destination
- Data types must match (or be comparable)
- Typically, empty strings will be converted to nulls, so you will need to consider if the columns are nullable.

(to name a few - if you want to delve deeper, you might also need to look at custom delimiters between fields and records.  Don't forget, commas and line feeds are still valid characters in char type fields).

Anyhow, maybe it will work for you, maybe not.  Sure, you might still have to deal with the exporting of the data from Oracle, but it might ease the pain getting the data in.

Have a read:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I had a bear of a time getting the format file right for BCP, but it looks like this gets me most of the way. It works for databases on my localhost, but I get errors connecting to the remote server with my actual target DB. It's a bit onerous for multiple files, different formats and not terribly portable, but it's a big improvement if I can get the server to allow remote connections... guess I'll bug the DBA again. Thanks Ash

Comment: Once you get it right, though, it should be reasonably bullet proof.  I am currently BCPing out from Sybase ASE and BCPing in to SQL Server 2016 over 300 Million rows daily.  We actually use it as it performs a lot quicker then through SSIS Data flow tasks and transformations.  The biggest issues we have are network dropouts and unknown updates to tables (which you will get anyway using SSIS).  All the best!